# How can I group this array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

I have this array of hashes:

```
- :name: Ben
  :age: 18
- :name: David
  :age: 19
- :name: Sam
  :age: 18
```

I need to group them by `age`, so they end up like this:

```
18:
- :name: Ben
  :age: 18
- :name: Sam
  :age: 18
19:
- :name: David
  :age: 19
```

I tried doing it this way:

```
array = array.group_by &:age
```

but I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `age' for {:name=>"Ben", :age=>18}:Hash):
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The `&:age` means that the `group_by` method should call the `age` method on the array items to get the group by data. This `age` method is not defined on the items that are Hashes in your case.

This should work:

```
array.group_by { |d| d[:age] }
```

Also with newer Ruby versions you can use the following shortcut:

```
array.group_by { _1[:age] }
```

`_1` here reflects the first positional argument of the block passed to the `#group_by` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
out = {}
array_of_hashes.each do |a_hash|
  out[a_hash[:age]] ||= []
  out[a_hash[:age]] << a_hash
end
```

or

```
array.group_by {|item| item[:age]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out ruby's `Symbol#to_proc` method is invoked and calls the `age` method on each hash in the array. The problem here is that the hashes do not respond to an `age` method.

Now we could define one for the Hash class, but we probably don't want it for every hash instance in the program. Instead we can simply define the `age` method on each hash in the array like so:

```
array.each do |hash|
  class << hash
    def age
      self[:age]
    end
  end
end
```

And then we can use `group_by` just as you were before:

```
array = array.group_by &:age
```