# Rails: how to group an array of structs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, struct

I'm using some code adapted from Railscast #213 for calendars. I have a model `Calendar` with many `Events`. Presently, in my controller, I have:

```
@events_by_date = @calendar.events.group_by(&:event_date)
```

This returns a hash of arrays grouped by `event_date` which is a virtual attribute of `Events`:

```
{ Tue, 01 Jul 2014=>[#<Event...>, #<Event...>, ...],
  Wed, 02 Jul 2014=>[#<Event...>, #<Event...>, ...],
  ... }
```

What I need to do is this: instead of the above, take each `Event` in the original set of ungrouped events, and put it in an `EventHolder` struct such as the following:

```
EventHolder = Struct.new(:event, :position)
```

where `:event` will hold the `Event` record, and `:position` needs to hold a value associated with the record, but that is not part of the record itself. I need it to be this way because each `Event` will need to live in (be copied to) multiple arrays and have a different `:position` in each instance.

For instance:

```
event_list = Array.new
@calendar.events.each do |event|
  event_holder = EventHolder.new
  event_holder.event = event
  event_holder.position = 1
  event_list.push(event_holder)
end
```

This works fine so far, giving me an array of structs like so:

```
[#<struct Calendar::EventHolder event=#<Event ...>, position=1>,
 #<struct Calendar::EventHolder event=#<Event ...>, position=1>,
 ...]
```

So far so good. But now, what I need to do is group those structs by the same virtual attribute `event_date` in my `Event` model. Just like the original statement, but grouping the structs instead of the events themselves. What I'd like to emerge with is something like this:

```
{ Tue, 01 Jul 2014=>[#<struct Calendar::EventHolder event=#<Event ...>, position=1>,
                     #<struct Calendar::EventHolder event=#<Event ...>, position=1>,
                     ...],
  Wed, 02 Jul 2014=>[#<struct Calendar::EventHolder event=#<Event ...>, position=1>,
                     #<struct Calendar::EventHolder event=#<Event ...>, position=1>,
                     ...],
  ...}
```

Essentially, I'm looking for almost exactly what I had with the original `group_by` method, only I want each `Event` to be packaged in *something* where I can have them grouped by `event_date` as before, but associated with a `:position` attribute that is *not* part of the `Event' record itself. I chose struct, but I'm not married to that.

How could I do this cleanly an elegantly? Am I even using the right approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had been using this statement on `event_list`

```
event_list.group_by(&:event.event_date)
```

It was throwing an error. This was the one that did the trick though:

```
event_list.group_by{ |e| e.event.event_date }
```

I got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136936/how-can-i-group-this-array-of-hashes). Still trying to figure out [Blocks, Procs, and Lambdas](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-on-rails-study-guide-blocks-procs-and-lambdas--net-29811). One day I'll get the hang of it.